# Migraines and tryptophan

Tags: medications, migraine, ssri-selective-serotonin

One theory about migraines is that it is triggered by dropping serotonin levels.
One medication, sumatriptan, acts by raising serotonin acting as a reuptake inhibitor.
Since tryptophan is converted into serotonin, can tryptophan supplements aid in fighting migraines. Is there any study in this regard?

Comment: You said that *"One theory about migraines is that it is triggered by dropping serotonin levels"*. If [tryptophan **is** converted into serotonin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908021), then surely this raises serotonin levels counteracting the drop in serotonin, therefore helping to fight migraines.

Comment: I do think that is the reason, but I would need to look up studies on it to be certain.  Because remember, even when the theoretical application of a concept makes sense, whether or not it is the primary mechanism for clinical effectiveness in vivo is a completely different thing.  There are plenty of meds that medicine thought worked one way but after additional study, turned out to actuality work a completely different way.

Comment: @DoctorWhom  that is why I am posting the question. There are several issues, including permeability of BBB to tryptophan, etc. I am wondering if they have done clinical trials on this

Comment: Yes, it is a good question. Sorry, my comment was aimed @ChrisRogers :)

Comment: @DoctorWhom  btw, great nickname!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sumatriptan activates *vascular* [5-HT<sub>1</sub> receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT1_receptor).  This results in vasoconstriction, which is what is thought to help the migraines.  This is the same idea for giving caffeine, which is also a vasoconstrictor.  Taking tryptophan would likely be ineffective for a variety of reasons in terminating a migraine.  First, it would have to be ingested and absorbed, which takes time, and then it would have to be metabolized to 5-HT ([Serotonin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin)).  Even if tryptophan was absorbed in the stomach, it would be ineffective at terminating the migraine in a timely fashion and thus not well tolerated by a patient.

Second, there is little evidence that oral tryptophan supplementation increases serotonin levels ([Cynober et al., 2016](https://doi.org/10.3945/jn.115.228478)).

[Cynober et al. (2016)](https://doi.org/10.3945/jn.115.228478) states that the subjects urinated out the tryptophan in a "dose dependent fashion."  Further, there was no significant change in their mood with tryptophan supplementation at any dose.  This suggests that the tryptophan is not being metabolized into 5-HT.  This makes sense, since tryptophan is in our diets, and it would be wild to think that our bodies didn't regulate 5-HT metabolism (that is to say that our bodies just automatically made 5-HT every time we ate something with tryptophan in it).

If patients do have a serotonin imbalance, it is likely involved in metabolism issues, say some mutation or problem with co-factors or enzymes.  Therefore, tryptophan likely isn't a solution.

### References

Cynober, L., Bier, D. M., Kadowaki, M., Morris Jr, S. M., Elango, R., & Smriga, M. (2016). Proposals for Upper Limits of Safe Intake for Arginine and Tryptophan in Young Adults and an Upper Limit of Safe Intake for Leucine in the Elderly–3. *The Journal of nutrition, 146*(12), 2652S-2654S. doi: [10.3945/jn.115.228478](https://doi.org/10.3945/jn.115.228478)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I read that 5-HTP can be more readily cross the BBB and they eliminate one step (https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/integrative-mental-health-care/201709/l-tryptophan-and-5-hydroxytryptophan-in-mental-health). Would that be more effective in fighting migraines?

Comment: So, while 5-HTP does appear to help with mood much more than L-tryptophan there is poor evidence to support 5-HTP yet for migraines (which isn't to say that it doesn't help).  The way that Imitrex works is that it directly activates the 5-HT1 receptors and causes vasoconstriction.  The way that 5-HTP would have to work is to either directly activate or inhibit receptors, or be metabolized into something that does.  The OP was wondering -- I think -- if tryptophan could work like Imitrex, and I think the answer is probably no.

Comment: This is a good paper with some thoughts about migraine pathophysiology. Kokavec, A. (2016). Migraine: A disorder of metabolism? Medical Hypotheses, 97, 117–130. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mehy.2016.10.029

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to either of the papers you linked, but thanks for the answers

Comment: @user - A pdf of Cynober et al. (2016) can be downloaded from  https://academic.oup.com/jn/article-pdf/146/12/2652S/23968978/jn228478.pdf

Comment: @ThomasTJCheckley See  [Wong, Andrea C., et al. "Serotonin reduction in post-acute sequelae of viral infection." Cell 186.22 (2023): 4851-4867](https://www.cell.com/cell/pdf/S0092-8674(23)01034-6.pdf) re plasma levels of serotonin can be restored via 5-hydroxy-L-tryptophanadministered in drinking water. I note that this  does not mean that circulating serotonin crosses the blood-brain barrier. They found rather a novel influence on the brain via afferent sensory neurons, in particular the vagus nerve.